# Iterator generics, cannot declare an iterator of mismatching types (maybe casting issue)

Tags: java, generics, iterator

I have this simple code

```
public String toString() {

   **Iterator it = list.iterator();**
   String s;

   while(it.hasNext()){

     s = s + " " + Integer.toString(it.next());

   }
   System.out.println(s);

 // IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD VIA AN ITERATOR

 // MAKE SURE THE OUTPUT PRODUCED BY THE METHOD
 // DISPLAYS THE LEAST SIGNIFICANT BIT TO THE RIGHT.

  }
```

At the line with asterisks, I get the following compilation error.

```
Error: incompatible types
  required: Iterator
  found:    java.util.Iterator<java.lang.Integer>
```

I already tried this,

```
**Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();**
```

I get, `Error: type Iterator does not take parameters`

EDIT ***

I forgot to mention, I have my own implementation of the interface methods.

```
/*
   * Inner class to implement the iterator for the <code>BitList</code>.
   */
  private class BitListIterator implements Iterator {

    /*
     * A reference to the current <code>Node</code> in the iterator. 
     */
    private Node current = null;

    /*
     * The expected modification count variable.
     *  Needed for the "fast-fail" implementation of the iterator.
     */    
    private int expectedModCount = modCount;

    /*
     * Advances the iterator to the next element in the list.
     */
    public int next() {
      checkValid();

      if (current == null) {
        current = first ;
      } else {
        current = current.next ; // move the cursor forward
      }

      if (current == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException() ;

      return current.value ;
    }

  /**
   * Inserts a new <code>int</code> value immediately before the next element that would be returned by <code>next()</code>.
   */    
    public void add(int newElement) {
      Node newNode;

      if (current == null) {
        first = new Node(newElement, first);
        current = first;
      } else {
        current.next = new Node(newElement, current.next);
        current = current.next;
      }

      modCount++ ;
      expectedModCount++ ;
    }

  /**
   * Indicates whether there is a next element in the list being traversed or not.
   */      
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return ((current == null) && (first != null)) ||
        ((current != null) && (current.next !=null));
    }

  /**
   * Checks whether this iterator remains valid, i.e. no concurrent modifications have been made on the list.
   */      
    private void checkValid() {
      if (expectedModCount != modCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
  } // end of BitListIterator class
```

So if import the package I get the following errors

```
Error: BitList.BitListIterator is not abstract and does not override abstract method remove() in java.util.Iterator

Error: next() in BitList.BitListIterator cannot implement next() in java.util.Iterator
  return type int is not compatible with java.lang.Object
```

I have jdk 1.7 and its in use.

Any ideas would certainly help.

Thank you,

Mjall2

Comment: The compiler is correct.  You haven't implemented `remove()` and your definition of `next()` is incompatible with the `next()` defined in the `Iterator` interface.  You'll need to fix those problems if you're going to use your iterator class.

Comment: What type is `list`?  Is it `BitList`?  Are you trying to have your `BitList` class return your `BitListIterator` implementation when `iterator()` is called?

Comment: make sure you don't have a class file named Iterator.class in the same directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you haven't declared `list` with a type. Try this:

```
private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Also, the message suggests you've imported the *wrong* `Iterator` class, which can happen if you aren't careful when using your IDE. Ensure `import java.util.Iterator;`, and no other import of an Iterator class, appears at the top of your java file.

Comment: While it's not explicit from the code, I think the `list` is supposed to be an instance of the (as yet unseen) `BitList` class whose existence is implied by the presence of the `BitList.BitListIterator` class that's been added to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you haven't got `import java.util.Iterator;` at the top of your file.

Comment: @Mjall2: That looks like a completely unrelated issue.  Your first code snippet isn't using `BitListIterator`.

Comment: @Mjall2: Do you have "`import java.util.Iterator;`" in your first code snippet?